# How to match numbers ranging from 400 to 550 with regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to validate a numeric string that must only contain numbers ranging from **400** to **550**.

```
$x = "401";  // valid 
$x = "551";  // invalid
```

I want to only match the numbers between **400** and **550**.

I tried the following pattern:

```
if(preg_match_all("/[400-550]+/",$x));
```

But it doesn't work.

What is the regex pattern for matching numbers 400-550?

Comment: want to use "range" instead? http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: Why do you want to do it via regex?

Comment: learning basic regex syntax would help. `[...]` defines a character CLASS, which matches a SINGLE CHARACTER in the target text, `[400-500]` is basically saying find one spot in the string where a character is either `4`, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, or `5`. e.g. `[400-500]` is functionally identical to `[0-5]`.

Comment: I'm with @anubhava here - unless you have a specific reason to use a Regex, this seems a little like an XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The thing you seem to really be asking here is how to find if a number is in a numeric range, at least not assuming anything outside of what you've included in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regex-way to validate this range:

```
\b(?:4[0-9]{2}|5[0-4][0-9]|550)\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH9lT8/3). It will also work in larger texts since `\b` boundaries are used. In case of whole strings, use `^` and `$` around instead of `\b`.

Comment: Stribiz , thank you. your solution is really helpful.

Comment: Feel free to mark as accepted :-) BTW, your original regex matched numbers consisting of digits from 0 to 5, of any length, because you put the numbers into a character class. 0-5 formed a range.

Answer (score 6):

Just combine [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), like this:

```
if(!in_array($x, range(400, 550)))
   echo "in ";
echo "valid";
```

Or just do a simple if statement, e.g.

```
if($x >= 400 && $x <= 550)
```

Comment: It is seducting to do that but don't forget that `range()` creates an array (with 150 items).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte updated my answer. And if OP wants to exclude certain numbers from this range, he can use `range()` and just remove numbers from the array.

Comment: Bah! If he wanted this kind of thing, no one would have answered anyway. :)

Comment: Rizier , Your answer is correct but I did not not ask for a solution with php fuction Btw thanx for your cooperation.

Comment: @Starkeen You're welcome! (Not every time is the solution what OP wants, since OP may not know about other stuff)

Answer (score 4):

Should work :

```
^((4\d\d)|(5([0-4]\d|50)))$
```

Comment: I think the capturing groups are not necessary here. I'd go for non-capturing ones.

Comment: It may be faster, but capturing groups are an easy way to not make priority mistake

Comment: @Blusky: yes but you have made a priority mistake (even with capturing groups). The anchors are not in factor with the 2 branches of your main alternation.

Comment: @Blusky: It isn't, the start anchor only applies to numbers that begins with 4 and the end anchor only applies to numbers that begins with 5. In other words, the pattern will succeed with 4000 or 1550 (since ^400 and 550$ are found)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 if(preg_match_all("/(4\d\d|5([0-4]\d|50))/",$x)) { ... }
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/zU4vX8/2

Comment: This will match up to 559

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a reason to use a regex, just compare the numbers.

```
if ($x <= 550 && $x >= 400)
```

It'll be faster and easier to read than a regex or using array ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Try `/(([4][0-9]{2,2})|([5][0-4][0-9])|(550))/`
(I haven't tested it). I dont know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

The php code:

```
<?php
$subject = "550";
$pattern = '/4\d\d|5[0-4][0-9]|550/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: It does not match `501`.